# PHP transform URL but no special characters

Tags: php, url-rewriting

```
$url= "testę";
$urlLower = strtolower($url);

echo "$url<br> $urlLower ";
```

Outputs:

```
test%c4%99
test%C4%99
```

How to output

```
test%C4%99
test%C4%99
```

Comment: I guess you do not use `mbstring overloading` for the string functions in your installations? If not, then those "special characters" are not recognised as such inside your script. So there is no way for php to treat the `C` in a special way. On the other hand: if you configure php to use overloading of the string functions, then you will never see the "percent escaped sequence", instead you will see the original string including the "special character" in your output and the functions `strtolower()` and `strtoupper()` will work as expected.

Comment: Since it's an url, `strtolower()` is probably not the way to go. `urlencode()` is surely what you're looking for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to take a look at `urlencode:`

```
$url = 'testę';
$urlLower = urlencode($url);
```

Which will give you:

```
$urlLower = 'test%C4%99'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: There is a f for it? Ouch :)

Comment: There's always a function for everything in PHP! Some call it sweet. Other's call it bloated.

Comment: Still have to investigate